# Intellij IDEA 16 background image

Tags: intellij-idea

How to remove background image of IDEA 2106?
After miss click in context menu of image file, idea have new background image(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know such a feature existed until now, but I've found your solution:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
- Type in "Set Background Image", and press enter
- In the dialog that shows up, click "Clear" in the bottom-right

After that you should be clear of any image overlay on the background.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't saw 'Clear' button before.) Now it's ok.